# How to select the parameter of the setCodec() function for audio recording in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, codec, qtmultimedia

I'm using QAudioRecorder in Qt to record a voice, here is the sample code.

```
audioRecorder = new QAudioRecorder;

QAudioEncoderSettings audioSettings;
audioSettings.setCodec("audio/amr"); //here's my question
audioSettings.setQuality(QMultimedia::HighQuality);

audioRecorder->setEncodingSettings(audioSettings);

audioRecorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.amr"));
audioRecorder->record();
```

But I have no idea how to use the setCodec() function

`void QAudioEncoderSettings::setCodec(const QString & codec)`

How can find out which parameter (such as `"audio/amr"` or `"audio/x-wav"`) I can use and their exact meanings? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could see the codec candidate in the source code for the [different plugins](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmultimedia/source/b088962950dbc4c6f0219de30b0d9a8cf47a3376%3asrc/plugins).

- [GStreamer](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmultimedia/source/b088962950dbc4c6f0219de30b0d9a8cf47a3376%3asrc/plugins/gstreamer/mediacapture/qgstreameraudioencode.cpp#L55-87)

  - audio/mpeg
  - audio/vorbis
  - audio/speex
  - audio/GSM
  - audio/PCM
  - audio/AMR
  - audio/AMR-WB
  - audio/FLAC
- [AudioCapture](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmultimedia/source/b088962950dbc4c6f0219de30b0d9a8cf47a3376%3asrc/plugins/audiocapture/audioencodercontrol.cpp#L94)

  - audio/pcm
- [QNX](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmultimedia/source/b088962950dbc4c6f0219de30b0d9a8cf47a3376%3asrc/plugins/qnx/camera/bbcameraaudioencodersettingscontrol.cpp#L58)

  - aac
  - raw

Answer (score 0):

You can call `supportedAudioCodecs` in the `QMediaRecorder` class to get list of supported codecs.

MWE:

```
    QAudioRecorder *recorder = new QAudioRecorder(this);
    QStringList codecs_list = recorder->supportedAudioCodecs();

    for( int i=0 ; i<codecs_list.count() ; i++ )
    {
        qDebug() << codecs_list[i];
    }
```